# CLLocationManager False didExitRegion

Tags: ios, timer, cllocationmanager

With CLLocationManager

I am defining regions and responding to didEnterRegion and didExitRegion.  This works fine in that I get the callbacks for the Enter and Exit as the device moves between regions.

**The problem** is that I have run the app overnight a few times with the phone device sitting on a table and not moving.  The phone device is in the center of an entered region.

During the night, about once an hour, I get a didExitRegion and then within less than 15 seconds I get a didEnterReqion.

My solution to filter these phantom exit/enter pairs was to set up a timer when I get an exit to wait 15 seconds and then if I do not receive an Enter for the same region within that timer window then I process the Exit.

This works if the app is in foreground, BUT in background it fails.  In background mode I still get the didExitEvent but I think the App is going back in to background mode before the 15 second window has elapsed do I don't fire that timer until the phone goes back in to foreground mode.

The Radius of my Region is 250M and the accuracy mode is nearest 10 meters.  My device, while sitting still, is centered in the Region and yet I still get these phantom Exit/Enter pairs once an hour.

Either I need to find a way to stop the phantom exit/enter pairs, or need a way to keep the timer running the full 15 seconds before the app moves back to background mode.

Does anyone have a good solution for dealing with random exit/enter or enter/exit pairs for stationary devices?

Also what is the max time that a timer can run upon an app waking event in background mode?

Comment: post your code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geofencing does not use triangulation (that's why "accuracy mode" you mentioned is totally irrelevant). Geofencing relies on a "digital signature" - set of wifi access points and cell towers your iPhone detected along with strength of signal coming from these sources. Whenever this digital signature changes, the phone might be fooled into triggering a geofence event.

However, before reporting the event, iOS runs triangulation (in most cases without GPS) - and the resulting location is available to you to check if you are really outside  the geofence. If location accuracy is too low relative to size of your geofence, you may obtain a better reading - requestLocation() will do the trick, as it will not run for more than 10 seconds.

By the way, that triangulation sequence the iOS runs after detecting a geofence event most likely is why your phone registers didEnter event shortly after didExit.

Arming a timer in background mode makes no sense, as iOS silently suspends background tasks after first 15 to 20 seconds of background execution. This behavior was introduced with iOS 7 and enforced for timers during iOS 10 lifetime.